# How to get marker details with legend if mark indices are used in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I have the following MWE in which only selected markers are only shown for second plot. As a result the marker goes missing in the legend entry as shown in figure (Case 2). How can I retain marker in the legend entry while using mark indices?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{filecontents*}{pgfplots.dat}
T   A  B  C
1.42857     6.616   6.697   6.782
1.40845     5.413   5.487   5.564
1.38889     4.544   4.612   4.684
1.36986     3.916   3.982   4.052
1.35135     3.469   3.534   3.603
1.33333     3.158   3.224   3.294
1.31579     2.954   3.022   3.094
1.29870     2.838   2.909   2.983
1.28205     2.795   2.870   2.949
1.26582     2.818   2.898   2.984
1.25000     2.905   2.992   3.085
1.23457     3.057   3.153   3.255
1.21951     3.278   3.385   3.499
1.20482     3.571   3.69    3.816
1.19048     3.922   4.052   4.188
1.17647     4.296   4.433   4.576
1.16279     4.645   4.783   4.927
1.14943     4.921   5.054   5.193
1.13636     5.085   5.208   5.335
1.12360     5.114   5.222   5.333
1.11111     5.007   5.097   5.19
1.09890     4.784   4.858   4.933
1.08696     4.477   4.536   4.596
1.07527     4.121   4.167   4.214
1.06383     3.742   3.778   3.815
1.05263     3.364   3.392   3.42
1.04167     3.001   3.022   3.043
1.03093     2.661   2.677   2.694
1.02041     2.35    2.362   2.375
1.01010     2.069   2.079   2.089
1.00000     1.819   1.827   1.834
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y,
        xmin=1.10,
        xmax=1.4,
        ymin=2.0,
        ymax=7.0,
        ]
        \addplot [solid,red,line width = 2.0] coordinates {(1.25,10) (1.25,0.01)};
        \addlegendentry{Case 1}        
        \addplot [smooth,line width = 1.0,mark=*,mark indices={4,6}] table[x=T,y=A] {pgfplots.dat};
        \addlegendentry{Case 2}        
        \addplot [smooth,line width = 1.0,mark=] table[x=T,y=B] {pgfplots.dat};
        \addplot [smooth,line width = 1.0,mark=] table[x=T,y=C] {pgfplots.dat};

    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 legend image post style={mark indices={}}
```

as option either for the single plot or for the axis environment.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}% <- set a compat! current version is 1.15
\begin{filecontents*}{pgfplots.dat}
T   A  B  C
1.42857     6.616   6.697   6.782
1.40845     5.413   5.487   5.564
1.38889     4.544   4.612   4.684
1.36986     3.916   3.982   4.052
1.35135     3.469   3.534   3.603
1.33333     3.158   3.224   3.294
1.31579     2.954   3.022   3.094
1.29870     2.838   2.909   2.983
1.28205     2.795   2.870   2.949
1.26582     2.818   2.898   2.984
1.25000     2.905   2.992   3.085
1.23457     3.057   3.153   3.255
1.21951     3.278   3.385   3.499
1.20482     3.571   3.69    3.816
1.19048     3.922   4.052   4.188
1.17647     4.296   4.433   4.576
1.16279     4.645   4.783   4.927
1.14943     4.921   5.054   5.193
1.13636     5.085   5.208   5.335
1.12360     5.114   5.222   5.333
1.11111     5.007   5.097   5.19
1.09890     4.784   4.858   4.933
1.08696     4.477   4.536   4.596
1.07527     4.121   4.167   4.214
1.06383     3.742   3.778   3.815
1.05263     3.364   3.392   3.42
1.04167     3.001   3.022   3.043
1.03093     2.661   2.677   2.694
1.02041     2.35    2.362   2.375
1.01010     2.069   2.079   2.089
1.00000     1.819   1.827   1.834
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y,
        xmin=1.10,
        xmax=1.4,
        ymin=2.0,
        ymax=7.0,
        legend image post style={mark indices={}}% <- added
        ]
        \addplot [solid,red,line width = 2.0] coordinates {(1.25,10) (1.25,0.01)};
        \addlegendentry{Case 1}        
        \addplot [smooth,line width = 1.0,mark=*,mark indices={4,6}] table[x=T,y=A] {pgfplots.dat};
        \addlegendentry{Case 2}        
        \addplot [smooth,line width = 1.0,mark=] table[x=T,y=B] {pgfplots.dat};
        \addplot [smooth,line width = 1.0,mark=] table[x=T,y=C] {pgfplots.dat};

    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to add `forget plot` to the `\addplot`, and use `\addlegendimage{line width=1,mark=*}` to populate the legend instead.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{filecontents*}{pgfplots.dat}
T   A  B  C
1.42857     6.616   6.697   6.782
1.40845     5.413   5.487   5.564
1.38889     4.544   4.612   4.684
1.36986     3.916   3.982   4.052
1.35135     3.469   3.534   3.603
1.33333     3.158   3.224   3.294
1.31579     2.954   3.022   3.094
1.29870     2.838   2.909   2.983
1.28205     2.795   2.870   2.949
1.26582     2.818   2.898   2.984
1.25000     2.905   2.992   3.085
1.23457     3.057   3.153   3.255
1.21951     3.278   3.385   3.499
1.20482     3.571   3.69    3.816
1.19048     3.922   4.052   4.188
1.17647     4.296   4.433   4.576
1.16279     4.645   4.783   4.927
1.14943     4.921   5.054   5.193
1.13636     5.085   5.208   5.335
1.12360     5.114   5.222   5.333
1.11111     5.007   5.097   5.19
1.09890     4.784   4.858   4.933
1.08696     4.477   4.536   4.596
1.07527     4.121   4.167   4.214
1.06383     3.742   3.778   3.815
1.05263     3.364   3.392   3.42
1.04167     3.001   3.022   3.043
1.03093     2.661   2.677   2.694
1.02041     2.35    2.362   2.375
1.01010     2.069   2.079   2.089
1.00000     1.819   1.827   1.834
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y,
        xmin=1.10,
        xmax=1.4,
        ymin=2.0,
        ymax=7.0,
        ]
        \addplot [solid,red,line width = 2.0] coordinates {(1.25,10) (1.25,0.01)};
        \addlegendentry{Case 1}        
        \addplot [smooth,line width = 1.0,mark=*,mark indices={4,6},forget plot] table[x=T,y=A] {pgfplots.dat};
        \addlegendimage{line width=1,mark=*}
        \addlegendentry{Case 2}        
        \addplot [smooth,line width = 1.0,mark=] table[x=T,y=B] {pgfplots.dat};
        \addplot [smooth,line width = 1.0,mark=] table[x=T,y=C] {pgfplots.dat};

    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```